# Wordpress is asking for ftp credentials

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress in apache2 om ubuntu. Now its asking for ftp credentials whenever I try to install any plugin or theme.

Since I dont want to disclose my server details with anyone, how I can overcome this issue.

Is there any solution for stop asking ftp credentials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck on this issue for last few days. Now I got a working answer from one of the comment.

Here I am attaching the changes I have made

```
sudo a2enmode rewrite
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

Hope this will help someone